# Can "we" be used as a polite substitute for "you"?

Tags: word-usage

Is it ever OK to use *we* as a substitute for *you*? Let me illustrate:

I am increasingly receiving emails from colleagues that contain sentences such as:

- Can **we** have a look at this tomorrow please?
- Can **we** ensure that **we** do not...

Now these emails seem innocuous enough, but I know full well that these co-workers have no intention of partaking in the tasks in question.

Would it not be better to say:

- Can **you** have a look at this tomorrow please?
- Can **you** ensure that **you** do not...?

Are these people trying to be considerate of my feelings by indirectly giving orders?

I find this use of *we* to be particularly grating, so some clarity regarding its correct use would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do they have authority to delegate or are they just trying it on. If the latter, talk to your line manager.

Comment: I think that's sometimes referred to as the "schoolteacher we".

Comment: I'm with you.  This practice is not polite, it is patronizing.

Comment: Fully agree, this is patronizing and condescending. Treating someone as a child. Also, it is a way of avoiding to be direct with someone. Instead of saying, "I need this by tomorrow" or "I want you not to mention the money issues in front of my parents".

Answer (score 1):

It is not an officially recognised 'polite term'to use we in place of you but is very frequently seen in the context you are describing.
The idea, as you suggested, is to create an idea of teamwork - an attitude of 'we're all in this together'if you will - and make it feel less like they are giving orders when in fact that is exactly what they are doing.

I agree with you that this transparent attempt to mask orders as teamwork is particularly grating when used repeatedly by people who have no intention of involvement, if you feel like being a bit cheeky you can always use their own words against them and ask when *we* shall be making these changes ;)

Comment: "Yes, I *can*, but the question is, *will* I?"

Comment: Can you name any ‘polite terms’ that **are** “officially recognised” as such?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You forgot to say "please".